# Feedback linearizion for input-output linearizion - Lie Derivatives

Tags: control-theory, nonlinear-system, lie-derivative, nonlinear-dynamics

Short introduction to feedback linearizion: If we got a nonlinear system:

$$\dot x_1 = x_2$$
$$\dot x_2 = a x_1 ^2 + bx_1 + c x_2 + u$$

and we want to have state feedback by using feedback linearizion technique. We can simply say that the control law is:

$$u = -Kx - ax_1 ^2 + r$$

Where $x$ is a vector of both $x_1, x_2$ and $K$ is an arbitrary control law matrix and $r$ is the reference vector. Now we have cancel out the nonlinearities for the system due to the $-ax_1^2$

But then there is something called input-output linearizion. That technique requires Lie Derivative.

Assume that we have a nonlinear system:

$$\dot x = f(x) + g(x)u$$
$$y = h(x)$$

For input-output linearizion, we say:

$$y^{(\rho)} = L^{\rho}_fh(x) + L_gL_f^{\rho -1}h(x)u$$

Where $$\frac{\partial h}{\partial x} f(x) = L_f h(x)$$

is called the Lie Derivative

So our control law will be:

$$u = \frac{1}{L_gL_f^{\rho -1}h(x)}[-L^{\rho}_fh(x) + r]$$

This control law reduce the system to:

$$y^{(\rho)} = r$$

Where $\rho$ is  is called the relative degree of the system.

**Question:**

1. How should I find $\rho$ so 
   $y^{(\rho)} = r$ ?
2. Why can't I use the control law $$u = \frac{1}{g(x)}[-f(x) + r]$$ instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You can find $\rho$ by repeatedly taking the derivative of $y$ with respect to time until that time derivative is a direct function of $u$. So the partial derivative of the $\rho$th time derivative of $y$ with respect to $u$ is none zero, however the partial derivative of the $\rho\!-\!1$th time derivative of $y$ with respect to $u$ is zero.
   Also note that $y^{(\rho)}$ is the $\rho$th time derivative of $y$.
2. You can only use the control law
   $$
   u = g(x)^{-1}(r - f(x))
   $$
   when $g(x)$ is a matrix with full column rank for all $x$ (when $g(x)$ is not square but has full column rank, then you could use the [right inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_element#Matrices)). When it does not have full column rank, then the inverse is not defined. Unless you choose $r$ such that $r - f(x)$ always lies inside the column space of $g(x)$, but that puts constraints on $r$.

From this it can also be noted that for the input output linearization method the inverse of $L_g\,L^{\rho-1}_f\,h(x)$ might also not always be defined. For example when the relative degree $\rho$ changes as a function of $x$. However for a lot of common systems it is more often then not well defined compared to the inverse of $g(x)$. For example the inverse of $g(x)$ is never defined for SISO systems with the dimension of $x$ larger then one.

Comment: So I need to derive the $y$ with respect on time over and over again so sooner or later becomes $y = u$?

Comment: @DanielMårtensson If you mean the following then yes:
$$
y^{(k)} = \frac{d^k\,y}{dt^k} = \alpha_k(x)+\beta_k(x)\,u
$$
where $\beta_k(x)=0$ for all $k<\rho$ (for $k>\rho$ $y^{(k)}$ would also be a function of time derivatives of $u$).

Comment: Does feedback linearizion  works well or is it another theoretical method? Theoretical control theory i.m.o is that you find the tuning parameters from the simulation, and apply them into real embedded control systems. I would not do that because even if I have a nonlinear model, that model is still an approximation. Example: H-inf according to me is a very theoretical control method who not works good in real systems. H-inf is very good for experiments in a laboratory.

Comment: I know that it sounds weird that I first asking how it works, then asking if the controller is used. But I'm trying to learn nonlinear control and focus only on control methods who works. Sliding mode control is an example on a control methods which works very well.

Comment: @DanielMårtensson I do not have much practical control experience, however I do know that this input-output linearization method will suffer from model uncertainties and disturbances. But other methods will more or less also suffer from this as well. The main problem with nonlinear control is that you can not decouple the observer from the feedback, so proving (global) stability is difficult.

Comment: Yes i know that feedback linearization will siffer from model uncertainites and distrubances. It's OK in my opinion because when I tune in a controller, i tune in when the controller and the system is built. I only build the shell of the controller and try an approximation simulation in the computer. That's why I don't see any idea to compute the tuning parameters in a PC simulation, then apply those onto the mikrokontroller  :) feedback linearization in a different method when you only need take the derivative of $y$ to find your control law. That's why I think it will work in real systems.

Comment: Hi, would you please look and give some suggestions to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4184228/lie-derivatives-book-or-references) question? Apparently several DG guys (including me) are confused there. We have no idea how Lie derivative is used in control theory and probably you can give better advice to the OP there.