# Lie derivatives: book or references

Tags: reference-request, lie-algebras, control-theory, nonlinear-system, lie-derivative

What are recommended references for Lie algebra, with a focus on the calculus with Lie derivatives of functions?

I refer to the case, where the Lie derivative is reduced to the directional derivative. The following definition is from the lecture on Nonlinear systems of H. K. Khalil

[https://www.egr.msu.edu/~khalil/NonlinearSystems/Sample/Lect_22.pdf](https://www.egr.msu.edu/%7Ekhalil/NonlinearSystems/Sample/Lect_22.pdf)

This is an excerpt:

> $$\dot x= f(x)+g(x)u, \ \ \ \ y=h(x),$$
> where $f$, $g$, and $h$ are sufficiently smooth in a domain $D$. $f :D\to\mathbb R^n$ and $g:D\to\mathbb R^n$ are called vector fields on $D$.
> $$\dot y=\frac{\partial h}{\partial x}[f(x)+g(x)u]=:L_fh(x)+L_gh(x)u.$$
> $$L_fh(x) =\frac{\partial h}{\partial x}f(x)$$
> is the Lie derivative of $h$ with respect to $f$ or along $f$.

Comment: What is that $\nabla hf$? What does $\nabla$ mean here?

Comment: It means the gradient. I remarked it in the edited question.

Comment: There is no such thing as gradient of vector fields on a smooth manifold. Are you restricting yourself to $\mathbb R^n$?

Comment: Yes exactly, $x\in\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: Now I read your formula again, that just looks wrong... why is there no derivative involved for $f$?

Comment: Regarding the restriction on x: I have only encountered such cases yet (nonlinear control theory). Why should there a derivation on f in this notation $L_fh$, which says derivative of h in the direction of f$? I know only this notation, where only $h$ is differentiated.

Comment: Most books on manifolds cover this material, but I don't know what's a good match for your background in control theory. <> The usual definition of the Lie derivative of a vector field is to specify the action as a first-order differential operator on test functions: $(L_fh)\phi = (fh - hf)\phi$, which one expands by writing $f$ and $h$ in Cartesian components, using the product rule, and noting that the second-order derivatives cancel by equality of mixed partials. But as Arctic Char says, the formula has derivatives of both vector fields, contrary to a Lie derivative of a _function_.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I edited the question, and I hope this is more precise. The definition in your comment looks for me related to the Lie bracket

Comment: It will be much easier if you link to some text where you see jow they are used, so that we know what is involved.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang  thanks for the explanations. I found out that what I knew about Lie derivatives was only with respect to scalar vector fields. If you could recommend any literature in this regard I would be pleased.

Comment: @ArcticChar thanks for the explanations. As written above I found out that the definition that I knew is for scalar vector fields. A linked an example.

Comment: What in the world are *scalar vector fields*? Do you mean actual functions? Do you mean vector fields on submanifolds of Euclidean space? And don't tell me to look at your link; it didn't load for me. Make your post self-contained if you want attention.

Comment: @TedShifrin functions actually.

Comment: So, yes, the Lie derivative is totally unnecessary baggage. The Lie derivative of a function at $p$ in the direction of a vector field $X$ is just the usual directional derivative in the direction $X(p)$. What exactly, then, is your question?

Comment: The question is still regarding a reference of calculus of such Lie derivatives. These are actually extensively used in nonlinear control, and I would like to read some background.

Comment: I know references only to standard graduate texts on differentiable manifolds. John Lee, Spivak volume 1, Boothby, and dozens of others.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you, sounds good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend Boothby's [book](https://g.co/kgs/BCWpQm) for a mathematically-oriented, yet fairly clear presentation. Check out Isidori's [book](https://g.co/kgs/RDbfrA) too if you need to see applications in nonlinear control.